# Once a cheater, always a cheater

Tags: idioms

I wonder if the title phrase is ever used in a meaning different from the obvious one: cheating in a relationship? Can it refer to cheating in an exam or obtaining money in a dishonest way?

Comment: The phrase can refer to all sorts of *cheating*. Not all people remain a cheater, though.

Answer (score 5):

The "**Once a, always a**" is a common saying and can be used to illustrate multiple situations:

> **once a ——, always a ——**
>
> proverb: *A person cannot change their fundamental nature*
>   once a whinger, always a whinger

([Oxford Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/once-a-%E2%80%94%E2%80%94-always-a-%E2%80%94%E2%80%94))

So yes, you can use it for other types of cheating as well.

Comment: Thank you, that helped :) When I googled the phrase, the first 30 hits referred to cheating in a relationship ...